# Drupal: allowing users to sign up to content using a form

Tags: drupal

My apologies if this is a little broad, but I'm struggling to know where to start here!

---

OK, so I have a Drupal site and I need users to be able to sign up for certain content, here is the workflow in detail:

I need a form within a block consisting of the following elements:

```
First Name (required)
Last Name (required)
Organisation (optional)
Email Address (required)
```

Then there will be a choice of content to sign up to (using checkboxes):

```
Policy Bulletin
Action News
eBulletin (which only members can sign up to)
```

Then the usual submit button of course!

Upon submission, users will:

1) Be taken to a confirmation page, or
2) Be informed about incorrectly filled in fields, and/or the need to become a user to be able to sign up for the eBulletin (possibly even directed to the membership sign-up page).

Users will then receive an email when new content of the type(s) they signed up to is created, along with a link to the node. There should be details about how to unsubscribe within this email.

---

I have used the Subscriptions module in the past, but I am not sure if it is possible to use a sign-up form with it. Plus, there is the added complexity that one of the content types, eBulletin, is only available for site members.

Like I say, I'm struggling to know where to start, and any ideas would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if what you want is to collect user input and then use some other mechanism to act on it, then [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module will probably do all you need. if you have a newsletter type publication, then the [simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) module will fit this better.

Comment: is it possible to use a Webform form as a UI for the Subscriptions module?

Comment: I don't think so without some custom coding. If Webform has some kind of hook for form submission you could create a module that automatically signs up a user using the Subscriptions module when a webform is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Carrero is right. Sounds like [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) (version 7.x-4.14 is your best bet) and [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) (you can customize the look and feel of your newsletter here) modules are your best bet. And of course, you may want to write some custom code to take care of automatically signing up users when a webform is submitted.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me that this answer doesn't add much to Peter Carrero's- basically you are confirming that what he said is right. For that, it's better to upvote it (you have enough rep), and in case leave a comment on it (you need 50 rep for that, so for the moment you can't yet).